# Names with single quotes in Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Normally, when using Template Haskell, names of bindings and data constructors are quoted by prefixing them with a single quote:

```hs
showName, justName :: Name
showName = 'show
justName = 'Just
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for names whose second character is a single quote, because two single quotes with a single character between them are interpreted as a character literal. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: It seems [the user's guide is wrong](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/22236#note_455450) about there not being an escape mechanism! You can just add a space after the initial single quote. So... don't use the below hack.

---

It's possible to work around this limitation using expression quoting and a bogus `Quote` instance.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}

module ExtractName (extractName) where
import Data.Functor.Identity
import GHC.Stack
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

extractName :: HasCallStack => Id Exp -> Name
extractName m = case unId m of
  VarE x -> x
  ConE x -> x
  _ -> withFrozenCallStack $ error extractNameError

newtype Id a = Id {unId :: a}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad) via Identity

-- This is bogus, but good enough for what we're doing.
instance Quote Id where
  newName _ = withFrozenCallStack $ error extractNameError

extractNameError :: String
extractNameError =
  "extractName: the argument must be an expression quote containing a\n"
    ++ "single bare name, such as [| f'1 |]"
```

Now you can write, for example,

```hs
f' :: Int
data Foo = B'ar

f'Name, b'arName :: Name
f'Name = extractName [| f' |]
b'arName = extractName [| B'ar |]
```

How does this work? An expression quote will produce an `Exp` in an arbitrary monad implementing `Quote`. In general, desugaring expression quotes may require the `newName` method, to desugar things like `let`s and lambda expressions. However, it does *not* need `newName` to desugar a plain old binding or data constructor. So we can write a bogus `Quote` implementation for an `Identity`-like type that will work for the sorts of quoted expressions we need. Once we've unwrapped the expression, we can extract the name from it.